# Assertion Failure on function using ispunct

Tags: c++, arrays, function, visual-studio-2012, ctype

I'm getting an Assertion Failure after building the "ReplacePuncsWithBlanks" function. Does it have anything to do with my inserting whitespaces to the beginning and end of the array?

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <ctype.h>

    using namespace std;

    const int SIZE = 100;

    void GetString(char StringArray[]);
    void CopyString(char StringArray[], char CopiedArray[]);
    void MakeUpper(char CopiedArray[]);
    void InsertBlanks(char CopiedArray[]);
    void ReplacePuncsWithBlanks(char CopiedArray[]);
    void DisplayString(char StringArray[], char CopiedArray[]);   

    int main()
    {
        char StringEntered[SIZE];
        char CopiedString[SIZE];

        GetString(StringEntered);
        CopyString(StringEntered, CopiedString);
        MakeUpper(CopiedString);
        InsertBlanks(CopiedString);
        ReplacePuncsWithBlanks(CopiedString);
        DisplayString(StringEntered, CopiedString);

    cout<<"Hit Enter.\n";
    cin.ignore();

    }
/***************************************GetString********************************************
*   Action:         Prompts user to enter some text.                                        *
*                                                                                           *
*   Parameters:                                                                             *
*       IN:                                                                                 *
*                                                                                           *
*       OUT:        StringArray which is the array holding the original text inputted by    *
*                   the user                                                                *
*                                                                                           *
*   Returns:        Nothing.                                                                *
*                                                                                           *
*   Precondition:   StringArray points to StringEntered array in Main.                      *
*********************************************************************************************/
void GetString(char StringArray[])
{
    cout<<"Please enter a sentence:  ";
    cin.getline(StringArray, SIZE);
}


/***************************************CopyString********************************************
*   Action:         Copies data from one array (StringArray) to another (CopiedArray).      *
*                                                                                           *
*   Parameters:                                                                             *
*       IN:         StringArray which has existing data.                                    *
*                                                                                           *
*       OUT:        CopiedArray which will be a copy of StringArray.                        *
*                                                                                           *
*   Returns:        Nothing.                                                                *
*                                                                                           *
*   Precondition:   StringArray points to StringEntered array in Main.                      *
*                   CopiedArray points to CopiedString array in Main.                       *
*********************************************************************************************/
void CopyString(char StringArray[], char CopiedArray[])
{
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; ++i)
    {
        CopiedArray[i]=StringArray[i];
    }
}


/**************************************MakeUpper*********************************************
*   Action:         Changes characters in the array to an uppercase letter.                 *
*                                                                                           *
*   Parameters:                                                                             *
*       IN:         CopiedArray which has mixed case letters.                               *
*                                                                                           *
*       OUT:        CopiedArray which will have uppercase letters.                          *
*                                                                                           *
*   Returns:        Nothing.                                                                *
*                                                                                           *
*   Precondition:   CopiedArray points to CopiedString array in Main.                       *
*********************************************************************************************/
void MakeUpper(char CopiedArray[])
{
    char c;
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; ++i)
    {
        c=CopiedArray[i];
        CopiedArray[i]=toupper(c);
    }
}


/***********************************InsertBlanks*********************************************
*   Action:         Moves elements in the array up one spot and replaces the first element  *
*                   with a space as well as the last element.
*                                                                                           *
*   Parameters:                                                                             *
*       IN:         CopiedArray prior to inserting the spaces.                              *
*                                                                                           *
*       OUT:        CopiedArray which will have a space in the first element and at the end.*
*                                                                                           *
*   Returns:        Nothing.                                                                *
*                                                                                           *
*   Precondition:   CopiedArray points to CopiedString array in Main.                       *
*********************************************************************************************/
void InsertBlanks(char CopiedArray[]){
    int temp=0;
    for (int i=SIZE-1; i>0; --i)
    {
        if(CopiedArray[i]=='\0')
        {
            temp=i+1;
        }
        CopiedArray[i]=CopiedArray[i-1];
    }
    CopiedArray[0]=' ';
    CopiedArray[temp]=' ';
    CopiedArray[temp+1]='\0';
}

/********************************ReplacePuncsWithBlanks**************************************
*   Action:         Changes characters which are punctuation to whitepaces.                 *
*                                                                                           *
*   Parameters:                                                                             *
*       IN:         CopiedArray which may include punctuation.                              *
*                                                                                           *
*       OUT:        CopiedArray which will have have replaced punctuations with whitespaces.*
*                                                                                           *
*   Returns:        Nothing.                                                                *
*                                                                                           *
*   Precondition:   CopiedArray points to CopiedString array in Main.                       *
*********************************************************************************************/
void ReplacePuncsWithBlanks(char CopiedArray[])
{
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; ++i)
    {
        if (ispunct(CopiedArray[i]))
        {
            cout<<CopiedArray[i];
        }
    }

}

void DisplayString(char StringArray[], char CopiedArray[])
{
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; ++i)
    {
        if(StringArray[i]!='\0')
        {
            cout<<StringArray[i];
        }
        else
        {
            i=(SIZE-1);
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;

    for(int x=0; x<SIZE; ++x)
    {
        if(CopiedArray[x]!='\0')
        {
            cout<<CopiedArray[x];
        }
        else
        {
            x=(SIZE-1);
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Any ideas on what it could be?

Comment: Can you show the code which allocates and populates `CopiedArray` please?  A definition of `SIZE` is important too.

Comment: added the rest of the code. thank you for looking at it.

Comment: The code works for me.  What input do you provide to make it fail?

Comment: To start, I was using really simple text, (hello, etc.) Could it be something with my Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the `main` function, both `StringEntered` and `CopiedString` contain garbage.

The `GetString` function reads a line from the input and replaces the *beginning* of `StringEntered` with what you entered. Then follows a `\0` byte, and the rest of the garbage remains.

Later, `CopyString` copies your input, the `\0` byte and the garbage to the `CopiedString`.

Then, the function `ReplacePuncsWithBlanks` operates on each byte of this block of memory. For each byte you call `ispunct`, and this function is very special. It doesn’t expect its argument to be of type `char` (which you probably thought), but rather to be of type `unsigned char`. See the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ispunct.html) for more details.

The problem is that a `char` can have a value between −128 and 127 on your platform, and the garbage at the end of the string surely contains some values that are negative. These values are not allowed as arguments to the `ispunct` function.

You are lucky that you got an assertion error. Your program could also have failed silently or made your computer explode. That’s called *undefined behavior*.

To fix this, you need to cast the argument to the proper type:

```
void ReplacePuncsWithBlanks(char CopiedArray[])
{
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; ++i)
    {
        if (ispunct((unsigned char)CopiedArray[i]))
        {
            cout<<CopiedArray[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Even better would be to stop the loop as soon as you see the end-of-string byte:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE && CopiedArray[i] != '\0'; i++) {
```

But even then do you need the type cast.